# Matlab - Send Variable From GUI to Function

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I am trying to call a GUI from a function, select an item from a pop-up menu in the GUI, and pass a variable associated with the pop-up selection back to the function. The only tutorials I find on GUIs have to do with just changing things within the GUI, but not sending anything out back to a main function.

So say I have 3 options in the pop-up: Image 1, Image 2, Image 3. When for instance Image 2 is selected and the OK button is pressed, I'd like the string 'Image 2' be passed back to the main function that called the GUI.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like: `[selection, ok] = listdlg('PromptString','Select a value:', 'SelectionMode','single', 'ListString',['Value 1';'Value 2';'Value 3'])`. The variable `selection` will give you the index of the selected value.

Comment: Thanks, kaloyan. That was exactly what I was looking to do!